# laravel mail send ordersmail to($var->email)

Tags: laravel, email, send

i am looking for a Answer for my Problem:

Controller

```
$data = array(
            'name'=> "Username",
            'omail'=>$request-> ordermail,
            'onumber'=>$request-> ordernumber
            );


            Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to($data->omail, 'User Name')->subject
            ('Order updated');
            $message->from('noreply@example.com','Name ');
            });
```

Output:

```
POST Data
_token  
"0ctXa44wTq10Jn89zxskAFwrQ7KOvO0lwJKXSkQ0"
onumber   
"DM122"
omail    
"mail@gmail.com"
```

I want to send mail after i have add a new record for an Order.
Its works fine when i fill `to('mymail@mail.com', 'My Name');` but when i try to send it to the POST Data, it doesnt works.

Best and thanks for every idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution that works:

added to Controller:

```
$_POST['to'] = $omail;
```

find and change:

```
$message->to($data->omail, 'User Name')->subject
```

changed to:

```
$message->to($_POST['to'], 'User Name')->subject
```